# Webcamera on my Sony Vaio PC

Tags: windows-7, webcam, sony-vaio

I recently purchased a new Sony Vaio computer, this one uses a AMD CPU, and has a "Sony Visual Communication Camera" camera.

problem is I get a very bad FPS with this camera, and comparison to earlier cams I used (Acer orbicam etc etc) this one seem to do 3-4 FPS

is there anything I Can do to speed it up, I.e. 25 FPS or use third party drivers or whatever ?

it seem not to be so good in darker rooms either comparison to the acer camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lighting is probably the issue here. The darker the room, the more your FPS will decrease. You could also try to fiddle around with it in post (Live Movie Maker does have a webcam feature worth checking out: http://explore.live.com/windows-live-movie-maker?os=other). But try playing around with the lighting and see if that improves your FPS.